# Gerar PDF/A com Jasper e Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Olá, eu estou tentando gerar um PDF/A com o jasper e Spring mas ele me da o seguinte erro:

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfXConformanceException: All the fonts must be embedded. This one isn't: Helvetica
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.internal.PdfXConformanceImp.checkPDFXConformance(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js10.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.addSimple(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js10.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfContentByte.setFontAndSize(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js10.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.writeLineToContent(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js10.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js10.jar:na]
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source) ~[itext-2.1.7.js10.jar:na]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.classic.ClassicPhrase.go(ClassicPhrase.java:76) ~[jasperreports-6.20.0.jar:6.20.0-2bc7ab61c56f459e8176eb05c7705e145cd400ad]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.writePageAnchor(JRPdfExporter.java:1076) ~[jasperreports-6.20.0.jar:6.20.0-2bc7ab61c56f459e8176eb05c7705e145cd400ad]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:1017) ~[jasperreports-6.20.0.jar:6.20.0-2bc7ab61c56f459e8176eb05c7705e145cd400ad]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:675) ~[jasperreports-6.20.0.jar:6.20.0-2bc7ab61c56f459e8176eb05c7705e145cd400ad]
    at com.larissa.arphoenix.projetopdfa.services.RelatorioService.exportarRelatorio(RelatorioService.java:42) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.larissa.arphoenix.projetopdfa.controllers.AlunoController.gerarRelatorioAlunos(AlunoController.java:80) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Meu RelatorioService:

```
public class RelatorioService {
    @Autowired
    private AlunoRepository alunoRepository;

    public String exportarRelatorio() throws IOException, JRException {
        List<AlunoModel> listaAlunos = alunoRepository.findAll();

        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/main/resources/relatorios/RelatorioAlunos.jrxml");
        JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(file.getAbsolutePath());
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(listaAlunos);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, new HashMap<>(), dataSource);
        JRPdfExporter pdfExporter = new JRPdfExporter();
        pdfExporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(jasperPrint));
        pdfExporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new FileOutputStream("RelatorioAlunos.pdf")));
        SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
        configuration.setPdfaConformance(PdfaConformanceEnum.PDFA_1B);
        configuration.setIccProfilePath("src/main/resources/ICC/sRGB_IEC61966-2-1_black_scaled.icc");
        configuration.setMetadataAuthor("LARISSA ROBERTA");
        pdfExporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
        pdfExporter.exportReport();

        return "OK";
    }
}
```

Meu JRXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.20.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.20.0-2bc7ab61c56f459e8176eb05c7705e145cd400ad  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Relatorio_Alunos_Unoesc" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="723c5b63-1da7-4637-936f-c709b5d7e36e">
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded" value="true" />
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name" value="src/main/resources/fonts/Helvetica.jar"></property>
        <style name="default">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2==0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style backcolor="#D6D6D6"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
<!--    <style name="default" isDefault="true" fontName="DejaVu Sans"/>-->
    <field name="matriculaAluno" class="java.lang.Long">
    </field>
    <field name="curso" class="java.lang.String">
    </field>
    <field name="emailAluno" class="java.lang.String">
    </field>
    <field name="nomeAluno" class="java.lang.String">
    </field>
    <field name="statusMatricula" class="java.lang.Object">
    </field>
    <field name="telefoneAluno" class="java.lang.String">
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="71" splitType="Stretch">
            <image>
                <reportElement x="40" y="7" width="89" height="63" uuid="9fecb2d7-0496-427d-a0ce-9216680ba2f3"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["D:/Projetos/Java/ProjetoPDFA/src/main/resources/Unoesc/unoesc.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="40" y="7" style="default" width="516" height="62" uuid="b4de6322-6cb2-4b38-8c28-bfc546c87367"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="30"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Relatório de Alunos]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="28" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="-1" y="4" width="555" height="23" forecolor="#D6D6D6" backcolor="#D6D6D6" uuid="fe6d23d5-ad62-4170-8b4f-ea3c35bf2602">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineColor="#D6D6D6"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="60" height="23" uuid="dffddc08-1205-4119-8cef-7fd0c7a14b5c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Matrícula]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="60" y="4" style="default" width="110" height="23" uuid="45d4ca13-c3ec-4bc5-a467-6acc961c03e9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nome do Aluno]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="260" y="4" style="default" width="132" height="23" uuid="77df6bd2-5536-4c3a-afa3-773739f7f757">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Email]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="391" y="4" style="default" width="88" height="23" uuid="1a57517a-e300-42c8-971f-affe90c455c9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Curso]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="479" y="4" style="default" width="75" height="23" uuid="70da3eff-f515-4bfb-932b-428dab21daa1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Status Matrícula]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="169" y="4" style="default" width="90" height="23" uuid="71b0e04c-a587-4644-864b-3e725a6ac51c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Telefone]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" style="default" width="60" height="18" uuid="ec4ef72a-6069-451a-ab21-0a45f900a19b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{matriculaAluno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="391" style="default" y="0" width="88" height="18" uuid="e1dfecdc-7e6e-4223-9476-5cfe3fd38522">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{curso}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="259" style="default" y="0" width="132" height="18" uuid="6208f587-8a7f-4db5-a08b-21edc8d2e877">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{emailAluno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="60" style="default" y="0" width="110" height="18" uuid="5d24da03-4142-4ab8-a384-3160f6c1132e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nomeAluno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="479" style="default" y="0" width="75" height="18" uuid="7ee58557-89eb-49e1-b847-e6589563569a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{statusMatricula}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement key="" mode="Opaque" x="169" style="default" y="0" width="90" height="18" uuid="99701627-c99b-411b-a0ba-5b7fd4cd2402">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="px"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="px"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                    <paragraph lineSpacingSize="1.0"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{telefoneAluno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="50">
            <textField evaluationTime="Page">
                <reportElement stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="245" style="default" y="30" width="62" height="16" uuid="52e42bab-3dbb-469c-83b5-b7b206479317"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Helvetica" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

e meu jasperreports.proprerties

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name=src/main/resources/fonts/Helvetica.jar
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=true
```

Alguém pode me ajudar? Eu tentei diversas soluções que encontrei na internet mas nada deu certo.

Estou usando o Java 17, Spring Boot 3 e JasperSoft 6.20

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro está faltando a fonte `Helvetica`. Já tentou seguir esse [passo a passo](https://thegeekyasian.com/add-custom-fonts-to-jasper-report-in-java-project-jaspersoft/)?

Comment: Eu segui os passos que estavam lá mas mesmo assim eu continuo recebendo o mesmo erro.

Answer (score -2):

Tente adicionar a seguinte dependencia em seu pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mpobjects.jasperreports.font</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts-liberation</artifactId>
    <version>2.00.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Este erro acontece quando voce esta utilizando uma fonte nao instalada no seu projeto.

Obs - se voce quiser imprimir no PDF esta fonte e necessário usar a tag pdfFontName, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="97" y="62" width="164" height="11" uuid="858074d4-1272-4e14-b433-bbc52ca701c6"/>
        <textElement>
            <font fontName="Courier New" size="8" pdfFontName="Courier"/>
        </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{descrTpmovprotv}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: eu tinha sugerido um tutorial na resposta acima, lá ele recomenda outra lib, mas está bem completo, eu fiz em comentário na pergunta acima